# Does "I be" mean both "am" and "was"?

Tags: tense, dialect

> I be traveling around the world.

Does it mean "I am traveling around the world" **and** "I was traveling around the world"? Does it indicate both of them?

Comment: It's using nonstandard grammar but since the (incorrect) verb form *be* is in the present tense, we assume that the correct verb form would also be in the present tense; so in normal grammar it would say "I am traveling around the world".

Comment: Please can you tell us where you found the sentence, *I be traveling around the world.*  Did you write it yourself or did you read it somewhere?

Comment: Some U/S slang uses "I be..." and "We be..."

Comment: Can it have been a fragment?

Comment: The biggest problem with this sentence is that I can't help reading it in a stereotypical pirate accent, and following it up with 'Yarr!'

Comment: @MrTheWalrus -  Arr, it be an American poirate though. Only one 'L' in traveling.

Comment: @chasly Er moight be good mummerset poirate wat cannot spell.

Answer (score 2):

It may be an instance of the "[habitual *be*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habitual_be)" used in some dialects (including the pirate stereotype @MrTheWalrus mentions).

Otherwise, "be" in a sentence like that can indicate the present tense subjunctive mood ("If I be travelling..."). This would only be the case if the sentence is somehow contrary to fact, conditional, or otherwise in the subjunctive mood. I think this use of the subjunctive is fading from some English dialects although I can't find a reference for this.

It is also possible that it is a simple error.

Comment: It's almost certainly the habitual. What traditional grammar calls the 'present subjunctive' has virtually vanished from every English dialect and register, except in clauses complementing 'mandative' verbs like *command, require, order, plead'. The mandative subjunctive is mostly a conservative US usage, but it is said to be reviving now in UK English.

Comment: Until the OP tells us the origin of the sentence we can't possibly know whether it is dialect or an error or anything else. Maybe the OP made it up.